# How can i prefill datetime_select with times in custom time zone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, ruby-on-rails-3.2, timezone, edit

I have **events** that can be in **different time zones**.

Upon **edit** I want the time & date to show with the time zone of that very event.

However, when I hit **edit**, `datetime_select` always shows the time of the users time zone (as opposed to the one of the event).

**Example:**

- Event starting at 10 a.m. in Amsterdam (GMT+1)
- Users time zone configured as London (GMT+0)

Result: *Upon edit the event time is falsely preset to 9 a.m.*

**Code snippet:**

```
def edit
  Time.zone = @event.time_zone
  @event.beginn = @event.beginn.in_time_zone
  @event.endd = @event.endd.in_time_zone

  # [...]
end
```

Note that **@event.time_zone** contains the desired time zone ("Amsterdam" in the above example).

**How can I have `datetime_select` preset to the events time in it's respective zone upon edit?**

Comment: I was able to confirm that this had been working correctly (with the same edit-action code) in Rails 3.2.6. A bug-report - including a workaround - is filed at https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9610

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **pixeltrix** pointed out in the thread of the bug report, it's cleaner to override the readers/getters of the attributes in question like so:

```
# in event model

def beginn
  super.in_time_zone(time_zone) if super
end

def endd
    super.in_time_zone(time_zone) if super
end
```

This way the logic in the **edit action** as outlined in the question can be omitted and interferences with other parts that rely on **Time.zone** are avoided.